# PHP Contact Form Coming From Admin's Email

Tags: php

I made a PHP Contact Form using [this tutorial](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/) and it works great, but I've encountered one potential security risk / inconvenience. Each email I receive comes from my admin login name.

I added `$headers` as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951792/php-reply-to-error-comes-with-admin-email-not-sender-of-contact-form) instructed, but to no avail.

**My Current PHP:**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = $_POST['email']; 
    $to = 'myClientsEmail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Estimate Contact Form';

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";                 /* I added this */
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";            /*     and this */

    $body = "From: $name\n Phone: $phone\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from, $headers)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

What exactly am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about this: `$headers = "From: $email\r\n"; ` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I added in hopes of changing the "From" in my email

Comment: What you want is this: `$headers = '"From: The Name <$email>\r\n";`

Comment: That threw an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$body' (T_VARIABLE)`, referencing the `$body` after headers, before the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `mail()` function call has an extra parameter it looks like. The correct `mail()` call should be:

```
if (mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
  ....
}
```

So just remove the `$from` portion and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the hasty reply! With those changes, the email no longer sends. I checked the inbox and spam mail. I also reverted it back to the original, and it came through again (just to make sure it wasn't the system)

Comment: You'll have to start doing some debugging. 1) Assign the `mail()` call to a variable. `var_dump()` that variable. 2) Check your SMTP settings on your server. It may be rejecting mail from a domain / user combo that is not the same as the admin username.

Comment: Not 100% sure if I did it correctly, but the end result was "Your message has been sent!" "bool(true)". I made `$mail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);` put `$mail` inside my if statement, and then did `var_dump($mail)` after the if else statement. Is that correct?

Comment: The mail didn't get there :/

Comment: Then check your SMTP settings on your server, or the acceptance settings on the mail you're sending it to. Likely it's another question for SO at this point, since there are lots of potential issues with troubleshooting a SMTP setup.

Comment: It's working now! I set up an email address to send from, and it's 100%. Thank you for the help!